# Symfony4 asset with parameter base_path

Tags: symfony4

Starting from the framework.yaml configuration file built as follows :

```
Framework :
    …
    assets :
        base_path : ‘/assets’
```

And the twig file base.html.twig' containing the following line :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/myVideo.css') }}" />
```

I thought I should put the css file in the `public/assets/css` directory,
but it is read from `public/css`.

Where's the mistake?

Comment: `Framework` key should be `framework` and `‘` should be `'`

Comment: So did you solve that problem ?

Comment: Now i use Webpack Encore

Answer (score 0):

My config file was correct, the syntax errors you report are only present in this post (bad manual transcription)
Here is the complete framework.yaml :

```
framework:
secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'

session:
    handler_id: ~

php_errors:
    log: true

cache:
translator: { logging:  false }

assets:
    base_path: '/assets'
```